# Programmatically access and modify.aspx page

Tags: python, html, asp.net, web, web-scraping

I am working on a project which needs to programmatically access and update a .aspx (ASP.NET) page. Specifically, I need to automatically access this page, use several html and JavaScript elements (click checkboxes, enter text in form fields, "click" buttons), and reload the page. Also, during the time the page is accessed, there is information being sent back and forth between the client and server.

What is the most efficient way to go about this? I am most likely thinking about writing something in bash + python to do this but I am not sure it is the best tool for the job.

Thanks

Comment: Reading and writing to aspx or ascx file is no different from a regular text file, as long as you do not modify or remove server controls. Where do you get stuck exactly?

Comment: @Win Looks like he intends to run the page and enter data in a form or similar. Not modify the actual code of the page. At least, that's how I read it.

Comment: @mason that is correct. I need to run tasks on the page programmatically. I.e. interact with the page like a user would, sending and receiving info to/from the server (which I do not control), just automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimal solution for your problem is using **Selenium** with python.

The selenium package is used to automate web browser interaction from Python.

```
pip install -U selenium
```

You can read [the documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html) to get familiar with the Selenium Webdriver API.

You cannot edit the pages that are hosted by others, but you can mimic the requests using selenium.